# Make a list of targets that each have different dependencies

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries

How can I write a Makefile to make a list of .so targets that each have different .o dependencies without writing out each .so rule individually?

What I basically have write now is every rule written out individually:

```
BUILD_SO=$(CC) -shared $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $? $(LDLIBS)

liba.so: foo.o bar.o epicfoo.o
    $(BUILD_SO)

libb.so: foo.o epicbar.o
    $(BUILD_SO)

libc.so: foobar.o
    $(BUILD_SO)
```

What I would like is to maybe be able to define variables at the top of the file like:

```
LIBA = liba.so
LIBA_DEPENDS = foo.o bar.o epicfoo.o

LIBB = libb.so
LIBB_DEPENDS = foo.o epicbar.o

LIBC = libc.so
LIBC_DEPENDS = foobar.o

ALL_LIBS = $(LIBA) $(LIBB) $(LIBC)
```

and somehow run them all through a generic rule that builds the targets similar to a `%.o:%.c` pattern rule, but instead more like

`%.so: <some list of .o names>`

Then have a .PHONY rule called libs so that I can call:

`make libs`

and have all the libs built.

Comment: Maybe [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
libadeps = foo.o bar.o
libbdeps = bar.o bar2.o
libcdeps = foo2.o foo.o

lib%.so: $(lib%deps)
    $(BUILD_SO)
```

I haven't tryed yet (I will because this will be helpfull to me too), but I think it will work.

Comment: @majorpain1588: Did you tried it? I haven't the time to try yet. I'm planning to use this in my project too.

Comment: I tried it on a small dummy project I made and it seemed to work.